# Managing image files in django. Separation of administrative photos of the site and photos of users

Tags: python, django

I'm begginer in django and doing my first car blog project. I am concerned about the question of how to correctly separate the photos that the user uploads to the page (when adding a new post, creating a profile, etc.) and the photos that are uploaded from the administrative panel (adding a photo category when creating it). As far as I know it is not recommended to store it all together.

I made the following directory:

[image]

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

Maybe there are some tips or solutions that are used in real projects.Thanks in advance!

models.py:

```
class CarCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/admin_images', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the model where you define the photo?

Comment: added at the end

Comment: How do you know your `CarCategory` is created by an admin/non-admin user? You don't link the user to the `CarCategory`?

Comment: sorry, fixed it. Categories will be added and edited exclusively from the administrative panel and images will be saved to admin_images. I'm generally wondering if this approach with photo storage directories is correct